# Godot Text Edit Node not wrapping

Tags: godot

Working on an app that is quite UI intensive in Godot and it seems the wrap_lines option isn't working on the text edit nodes.  it still scrolls horizontally as I type or if I set text it just does one long line.  Is there a second option I need to change in the node

Comment: Three years later, wrapping still doesn't seem to work for TextEdit

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar circumstance to your problem with my app and did my own custom solution. However, I am OK with just limiting the number of characters instead of wrapping the lines. My solution only covers limiting the line up to a certain number of characters. This is what I have for my solution:

```
func _on_TextArea1_text_changed():
    var temp = $TextArea1.text
    var maxTextSize = 9
    if temp.length() > maxTextSize:
        $TextArea1.text = temp.substr(0,maxTextSize)
```

Limitation: If I try to concatenate '\n' I get "Stack Overflow (Stack Size:1024)".

Resource: See https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_textedit.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Documenting how I fixed wrapping on my `TextEdit`:

The `text` property of your `TextEdit` node **must** be set **after** setting `wrap_enabled` to `true`. If you set `text` before, it will not be wrapped.

Took me hours to figure out what was going wrong. Extremely frustrating... Hope this saves someone else from the same.